# copying an android studio project and run two versions on smartphone

Tags: android, android-studio, copy, smartphone

I have copied an Android Studio project and changed the name. It builds and I can run it on the Samsung. But it replaces the original version instead of installing itself as a new app on the phone. It just changes the name of the app on the phone. Is there another setting I have to change?

Comment: change the package name of your application. In manifest file in <manifest></manifest> tag give package="your_packageName".

Comment: Ur application is identified by the package name , U have change that for new appliction

Answer (score 1):

The package name is the unique identifier for an android application.There can't be two apps with the same package name in the market/on the device
There is a good article about it [here](http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/)

You can use Flavours for run two versions on smartphone. For reference please go to the below link

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

http://blog.brainattica.com/how-to-work-with-flavours-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gradle, you can change it from your app.gradle under "android" section -> "defaultConfig" -> "applicationId"

Answer (score 0):

In android studio right click on your project. 
Open Module Settings-> Flavors Tab
There change the Application Id to different one to take new apk with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

No need of another copy of application just change the package name in Manifest file

```
package="com.example.myapplication"
```

Take a build with one package and another build with changed package name

like  `package="com.example.myapplication2"`